# Environment differences between Cygwin sshd vs the local console

Tags: windows, environment-variables, cygwin, sshd

I installed Cygwin, the release of Python for Windows from python.org, and the `tensorflow` package. I enabled the Cygwin OpenSSH server so I can connect remotely.

When I connect remotely, start Python, and `import tensorflow`, it cannot find a particular Cuda runtime library.

However, if I locally launch the Cygwin Terminal and do the same, `import tensorflow` succeeds.

What causes the latter case to work differently? Is there some library search path environment variable that is not inherited by remote connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use `declare > local_env.sh` on the local prompt and `source local_env.sh` on the remote prompt, and now the DLL is found.

I realized that over SSH, the `PATH` environment did not seem to include my CUDA directory.

It turned out that this was because I had installed CUDA *after* the `cygsshd` service had started. I had to restart the service to populate it with the new environment. After I did that, it worked fine.